# Windows volume control - application vs. device

Tags: windows, audio

My VoIP application is hosted on Win7. It includes volume control. Since Win Vista introduced the ability to control volume of each application individually via the mixer API, I chose that. So, I use:

- mixerOpen
- mixerSetControlDetail - to change my application's volume level
- mixerGetControlDetail - to fetch my application's volume level

The mixerOpen call is made with CALLBACK_WINDOW, and I have a window setup to capture control messages, including MM_MIXM_CONTROL_CHANGE. This event triggers me to refresh my volume level with a call to mixerGetControlDetail.

This works fine. I can goto the Windows Volume Mixer panel and make changes to my app's volume slider. I get the MM_MIXM_CONTROL_CHANGE message, and the value returned by mixerGetControlDetail has the updated level.

But, if I change the Device level, I get no such notification. If I query my application's volume level, it remains unchanged. Yet, the app's volume slider is changing in the Volume Mixer dialog as I slide the Device volume slider.

I thought I understood the differences in the mixer API and IAudioEndpointVolume(Callback), but apparently I'm missing something. Why does the mixer return the same volume level for my app even though the Windows Volume Mixer panel shows it changing?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is here already.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232125/getting-volume-change-notifications-on-vista-7-c

Comment: Reworded my question. I understand how to get change events for app levels vs. Device levels. What I don't understand is whether I should expect Device level changes to change the app's level. My code suggests the answer is 'no', but the Windows Volume Mixer dialog suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get it now and it makes perfect sense.

Application Audio -> App Volume Control -> Mixer -> Device Volume Control -> Device.

The Application Volume Control is indeed a separate control from the Device. The Windows Volume Mixer dialog slider is expressing the Application slider level relative to the Device slider level (i.e., level = (Device Level * (App Volume Control / max)) / max).

So, when both sliders start @ 100% (control value = 65536), then as the Device level is raised/lowered, the App level tracks it. But, if the App level started @ 50% (32767) of the Device Level, then the App level goes to 25% when the Device level goes to 50% (32767). The scalar of the App Volume Control stayed constant, but the slider level tracked the device level.