# Show Windows 8 Metro volume slider/notification/widget/indicator?

Tags: audio, windows-8, notifications, widget, microsoft-metro

I'm not sure how it is called... System volume widget? Metro audio notification? Anyway, I mean this thing:

[image]

It shows up in Windows 8 when you change the volume on a notebook using FN keys, such as FN+F12 for ASUS notebooks. Is this thingy included in the Windows API? I have created a C# tray application that that calls the Windows API to change the volume, however that does not trigger the widget. Is there a way to programmatically get this widget to pop up?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe [this questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232125/getting-volume-change-notifications-on-vista-7-c) has your answere. Maybe this here is useful too. [Peak Meter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316561(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: That question seems to be about being notified when the music volume has been changed in Windows 7. Since I'm changing the volume programmatically myself, I won't need help detecting that. The widget I'm trying to trigger is new in Winodws 8, so questions for Windows 7 or below won't be helpful. However, thanks for searching though. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's the systemmediatransportcontrol in windows.media. I haven't found anyway to address it directly in c# from a desktop app, BUT....you can use the windows media keys to send a volume up and volume down key, which will show that widget.

It's not the best, but it does work.